# Parsing text from reports

Tags: parsing, perl

I want to parse some reports from multiple devices, reports looks like this:

> ```
> VR            Destination      Mac                Age  Static  VLAN          VID   Port
> VR-Default    192.168.11.13    90:e2:ba:3c:95:c0    2      NO  intra1        350   49
> VR-Default    192.168.1.1      00:0e:a6:f7:b6:b5    0      NO  main          602   1
> VR-Default    192.168.1.2      00:0d:88:63:bf:d1    3      NO  main          602   1
> VR-Default    192.168.1.14     00:1c:f0:c7:d2:52    4      NO  main          602   1
> etc...
> Dynamic Entries  :          19             Static Entries            :          0
> Pending Entries  :           1
> In Request       :     3888802             In Response               :       4531
> and some more data...
> Rx Error         :           0             Dup IP Addr               :         0.0.0.0
> and some more...
> ```

I need only vr, destination, mac, age, static, vlan, vid and port fields.
I can parse it using `split` function and regexes, but split fails if one field (e.g. Age) is empty.
perldoc says I can use `unpack`:

```
my $template = 'A13xA16xA18xA4xA7xA13xA5xA*';    
for my $line ( split /\n/, $data ) {
   chomp $line;
   my ($vr, $destination, $mac, $age, $static, $vlan, $vid, $port) = unpack $template, $line;
...
}
```

But it dies on lines with length < 84. And I got to check string length every time (Or maybe using `eval` on unpack? Is it better?). And again I got to use regexes or `index` to find the end of main table and skip headers.
The code will looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $arp = <<'ARP';
VR            Destination      Mac                Age  Static  VLAN          VID   Port
VR-Default    192.168.11.13    90:e2:ba:3c:95:c0    2      NO  intra1        350   49
VR-Default    192.168.1.1      00:0e:a6:f7:b6:b5    0      NO  main          602   1
VR-Default    192.168.1.2      00:0d:88:63:bf:d1    3      NO  main          602   1
VR-Default    192.168.1.14     00:1c:f0:c7:d2:52    4      NO  main          602   1

Dynamic Entries  :          19             Static Entries            :          0
Pending Entries  :           1
In Request       :     3888802             In Response               :       4531
Rx Error         :           0             Dup IP Addr               :         0.0.0.0
ARP
my $template = 'A13xA16xA18xA4xA7xA13xA5xA*';
for my $line ( split /\n/, $arp ) {
   last if index( $line, 'Dynamic E' ) == 0;
   next if length $line < 84;
   chomp $line;
   my ($vr, $destination, $mac, $age, $static, $vlan, $vid, $port) = unpack $template, $line;
   next if $mac eq 'Mac';
   print "$mac - $destination\n";
}
```

**My question is:** how would you parse this data? split, regexes, unpack, substr or something else?

Comment: This question does not deserve to be closed — the second program works.

Comment: perhaps CSV module?

Comment: @mpapec I thought CSV module will fails when some fields will be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a problem has been encountered before by someone else, chances are that there is a CPAN module for that [(`DataExtract::FixedWidth`)](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DataExtract-FixedWidth/).

If you don't want to use a CPAN module, then my next choice would be to use regular expressions.

```
use strict;

# Strips leading and trailing whitespace from all parameters
sub strip {
    for (@_) { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; }
    @_;
}

# Extracts data from lines of text in tabular format.
#
# First parameter is a regular expression for capturing fixed-width fields.
#
# Subsequent parameters are the lines of tabular data, the first of which holds
# the column headings.  Any line that does not match the regular expression,
# as well as subsequent lines, are discarded.
#
# Returns a list (one element per input line) of hashes (keyed by column names).
sub extract_table {
    my ($fmt, $first_line) = (shift, shift);

    my (@headers) = strip($first_line =~ $fmt);

    my @table;
    for my $line (@_) {
        my (@fields) = $line =~ $fmt;
        last unless @fields;

        my %data;
        @data{@headers} = strip(@fields);
        push @table, \%data;
    }
    return @table;
}

my $fmt = qr/^(.{14})(.{17})(.{19})(.{5})(.{8})(.{14})(.{6})(.*)/;

# Take lines of input from a reasonable source (STDIN or a filename
# argument on the command line)
my @table = extract_table($fmt, <>);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@table);
```

Note that `chomp()` is unnecessary since we're stripping whitespace characters anyway.

Comment: It might be worthwhile mentioning that `strip(@fields);` also alters `@fields` array.